# VS2012 / Windows Phone emulator can't start

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone

I can't start the Windows Phone emulator in VS2012 ... I have downloaded the Windows Phone 8 SDK.

It launches, but gives me an error whilte booting:

"The Windows Phone Emulator wasn't able to ensure the virtual machine was running" ...
blalbla ... "... Element not found (0x80070490)

and something about not being able to find a useable certificate?!

Any ideas on how to get it up and running?

Comment: Please confirm you are trying this from Windows 8 only. Windows 7 is not supported for the Windows 8 SDK.

Comment: I have had this situation though emulators usually work fine. When this happens, I reboot my computer (Windows 8.1) to remedy this.  I do not the cause.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously this was caused by a permission issue.

My user account hadn't any permissions to the folder:  "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys". Giving my user account full access rights to this folder, seems to have solved the problem!